# Arreglo Java crear archivo txt pero se duplica infomacion

Tags: java, array, arraylist, txt

Estoy creando un archivo txt con diferentes nombres pero al crear el segundo y llenar la información esta se duplica, igual cuando vuelvo a llenar información en el primer archivo vuelve a traer información del segundo.

```
   public void Grabar(String tienda){


      try{

       PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("Usuarios"+tienda+".txt",false)));
          String linea;

          for(int i=0;i<empleados.size();i++){

              linea="Employee"+","+empleados.get(i).getDni()+",,1,99,,"+empleados.get(i).getPrimerNombreEmp()+
                           ","+empleados.get(i).getSegundoNombreEmp()+","+empleados.get(i).getApellidos()+","+empleados.get(i).getCargo()+","+
                    empleados.get(i).getEstado()+","+"2020-01-01,,,Lima,Perú,,,,"+empleados.get(i).getSexo()+
                    ",,,"+empleados.get(i).getTipocargo()+","+empleados.get(i).getTipocargo()+",00000000,,WKSTN,,,,,,,Perú,,,,,,,,,,,,,";
          pw.println(linea);


          }

          pw.close();
          System.out.println("Archivo modificado satisfactoriamente..");

      }catch(Exception x){


      }



    }
```

Por Ejemplo: lleno los datos que me pide la plantilla y creo un archivo TiendaPeru nombrea,apellidoa,dnia 
luego creo otro archivo TiendaChile con los datos `nombreb,apellidob,dnib` 
ahora abro los archivos Y visualizo que el archivo TiendaPeru tiene los datos correctos pero el archivo TiendaChile tiene los datos :

```
nombrea,apellidoa,dnia <== datos de peru  (incorrecto)
nombreb,apellidob,dnib  <== datos de chile (correcto)
```

y si vuelvo a llenar datos en el archivo TiendaPeru queda

```
nombrea,apellidoa,dnia   (correcto)
nombreb,apellidob,dnib   (incorrecto)
nombrec,apellidoc,dnic   (correcto)
```

y sucesivamente. 
el usuario puede crear diferentes archivos pero dentro de el la información debe ser distinta ya que pertenece a países distintos.

Comment: Podrias dar un ejemplo de lo que se duplica. En el código que pusiste no veo nada que se duplique, salvo que en otro lado estes inadvertidamente duplicando el contenido de `empleados`.

Comment: Por Ejemplo:
lleno los datos que me pide la plantilla y creo un archivo TiendaPeru
nombrea,apellidoa,dnia
luego creo otro archivo TiendaChile con los datos
nombreb,apellidob,dnib
ahora abro los archivos Y visualizo que el archivo TiendaPeru tiene los datos correctos pero
el archivo TiendaChile  tiene los datos
nombrea,apellidoa,dnia  
nombreb,apellidob,dnib  
y si vuelvo a llenar datos en el archivo TiendaPeru
queda
nombrea,apellidoa,dnia  
nombreb,apellidob,dnib 
nombrec,apellidoc,dnic  
y sucesivamente.

Comment: Las aclaraciones por favor agregalas a la pregunta editando la misma. En cuento a lo que comentas: Como se llena la colección `empleados`. Pareceria que ahí se te están agregando los empleados, por ahí sin haber eliminado los anteriores.

Comment: @Carlos, tiene toda la pinta de que está pasando lo que te comenta Juan, al cargar los datos en empleados no estás limpiando los datos anteriores con  `empleados.clear()` y por eso en el segundo fichero incluye los empleados del anterior.

Comment: @roberto  Gracias con clear lo solucione.

Comment: @juan gracias..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según el código no se aprecia nada que genere duplicados por lo que parece que el problema estaba en los datos de `empleados`, que no se limpiaban entre carga y carga.

Una solución sencilla es utilizar el método `clear()` justo antes de cargar los datos:

```
empleados.clear();
```

Otra opción podría ser crear un nuevo objeto previo a cada carga:

```
empleados = new ArrayList<>();
```